# Event Relay to AWS - Not Creating Partner Source in Event Bridge

Tags: aws

I've been trying out the newly launched Event Relay with AWS EventBridge integration based on this docs here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/event-relay/guide/relay-events-section.html

I've followed the steps but when I queried the following : SELECT Id,RemoteResource,Status,ErrorMessage,ErrorTime,ErrorIdentifier FROM EventRelayFeedback WHERE EventRelayConfigId ='Relay_Id_Placeholder', the RemoteResource is empty and there's no connection on EventBridge.

Is there an additional step that I need to configure at AWS in order for this integration to work?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well. The solution was to wait half an hour or so, then it came up.